# Can not find connectors in Confluent control center

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I am learning kafka with Confluent Platform. I have followed their quick start guide with docker. But when i was try to generate mock data for the topic i could not find connectors as in their guide. Then i spend days to try add connectors with  confluent hub client. I have downloaded the `tar.gz` file and extract it. As their documentation, path for `/bin` folder which contains `confluent-hub` file to path variables. Then i use `confluent-hub install confluentinc/kafka-connect-datagen:0.1.1` command. But it showed following error.

```
/c/Program Files/Docker Toolbox/bin/confluent-hub: line 13: cd: /c
Files
Toolbox/bin/../share/java: No such file or directory
Error: Could not find or load main class io.confluent.connect.hub.cli.ConfluentHubClient
```

Furthermore, i am using docker toolkit which installed in my windows machine.
Can someone help me to solve this problem.

Thank you very much in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

`confluent-hub` would need to be ran within the container, not from your Windows machine.

The alternative is to download the DataGen JARs yourself then volume mount them into the container under the `plugin.path` of the connect image.

Comment: I am very new to docker stuff. Is it possible to run confluent hub in the container using docker toolbox?

Comment: For simplicity, you don't need to reference "Docker Toolbox", underneath, it's still the same Docker commands. And yes, you should be able to following examples like this post to override the `command` flag to run `confluent hub install ... &&  /etc/confluent/docker/run`. **OR** you can use a volume

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I use this command. `confluent-hub install --no-prompt confluentinc/kafka-connect-datagen:0.1.0 && /etc/confluent/docker/run`. But still getting same error.

Comment: Where is that running though? I forgot to link this https://rmoff.net/2018/12/15/docker-tips-and-tricks-with-ksql-and-kafka/

Comment: I tried by updating `docker-compose.yml` but still i could not resolved this. When i ran `docker-compose ps` command there are few containers. What is exact container that i need to choose? Is it control-center or ksql-datagen ?

Comment: Neither? `kafka-connect` is where the connector is installed... I haven't used Control Center in years, so I can't say if the datagen connector will load within it

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the same problem, trying to install "mongodb/kafka-connect-mongodb:1.0.1".

I solve my problem following the tutorial that @cricket_007 wrote in his comment.

Create add service in your docker-compose that uses the image "confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect" or "cp-kafka-connect-base" and run a command to install your connector through the confluent-hub client.

```
kafka-connector:
  image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:5.3.3
  [...]
  command: 
    - bash 
    - -c 
    - |
      confluent-hub install confluentinc/kafka-connect-datagen:0.1.1
      /etc/confluent/docker/run
```

Or you can use a more direct solution

```
kafka-connector:
  image: confluentinc/kafka-connect-datagen
```

In my case I had to use the first solution, because the image 'mongodb/kafka-connect-mongodb:1.0.1' was not available.